# How do I turn off messenger in the new Hotmail UI?

Tags: outlook.com

Logging into hotmail logs me out of my MSN Messenger client since their last update.  Very frustrating.

Is there any way to turn off the Messenger web UI in Hotmail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Click your name in the upper right.
2. Click Sign out of Messenger.

This setting will be remembered the next time you load the page as well as the next time you sign if (if you log out).  Rather than loading your contacts, the Messenger area on the left will have a link to sign in.